# Is it possible to get Windows to include the file extension when renaming

Tags: windows

Whenever I try to rename a file in Windows 10, the behavior (since Windows 7) is to select only the file name, and not include the file extension.

In other words, when I try to rename `filename.txt`, only `filename` is auto-selected.

I understand **why** this is the default behavior (to stop non-techie users from accidentally renaming files to a point where they can't open them), but is there a Registry option to override this, so that it selects the entire `filename.txt`?

Obviously I can manually select as much as I want, but I'd love to change the default option.

Comment: This capability simply isn't built into Windows GUI file manager, you would need to use the command line, or a third party file manager like Total Commander (simply as an example, there are lots of choices) which supports this.